# AJAX POST method to Spring RestAPI not working

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, post

I'm trying to send a large form of data to my server side, using jQuery AJAX and sending it to a RESTful service made in the Spring Framework. And the form as arrays of unknown sizes, so am trying to get the auto serializing to work. But I can't even get it to work with a simple test example.

It seems to not be able to match my JSON file to the input class. So I must be doing something wrong. But I have not been able to see what I'm doing wrong based on the tutorials I have been trying to follow.

Here is my AJAX call

```
var test = JSON.stringify({
            name : "hallo", lastname : "there"
        });

        console.log(test);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/SpringTest_war_exploded/test",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: test,
            success: function (returnValue) {
                console.log("success");
                console.log(returnValue);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log (XMLHttpRequest);
                alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Here is my server-side method.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String testajax(@RequestBody TestAutoCreate  test){
    System.out.println("testajax");
    System.out.println(test.getName());
    return "hallo";
}
```

Here is the class I'm trying to match it with

```
public class TestAutoCreate {
    private String name;
    private String lastname;

    public TestAutoCreate(String name, String lastname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    // the getters and setters 
    ...
}
```

And here is the error massage I get

```
The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.
```

If I remove the `@RequestBody TestAutoCreate` test from the server side method, then the call works fine. It is only

Comment: Try to send the `test` variable without stringifying it (send the JSON object directly)

Answer (score 0):

The problem at here

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String testajax(@RequestBody TestAutoCreate  test){
    System.out.println("testajax");
    System.out.println(test.getName());
    return "hallo";
}
```

It is RESTful controller, but return view. You must return RESTful response, what has content type is `Content-Type: application/json` .

See authority example: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: I most admit, I'm not quite sure what it is your saying I should change ?

As a mentioned in my post, if a remove the input parameter from "testajax", it returns the string "hallo" fine no problems. It is only when I'm trying to auto deserialize it, into the  "TestAutoCreate" class, that I'm getting  the error, which states it could not find a match for my request. 

And the link you send, was one of the tutorials I referenced, that i tried to follow. But I'm quite new to Spring, and I most admit, that I'm not quite sure what I do wrong, compared to the tutorial